# How do I set the relative rank of a story or defect using the Rest api 2.0 in Java?

Tags: rally

I'm creating stories and defects via Rest api 2.0. I want to set the relative rank lower than other existing items that are already prioritized. This is possible with the SDK, what is the equivalent method in Java Rest 2.0?

from App SDK:

```
Rally.data.Ranker.rankRelative({
    recordToRank: recordToRank,
    relativeRecord: relativeRecord,
    position: 'after'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set the rankAbove or rankBelow param on the request:

```
JsonObject defectToRerank = new JsonObject();
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest("/defect/12345", defectToRerank);
updateRequest.addParam("rankAbove", "/defect/34567");
UpdateResponse updateResponse = restApi.update(updateRequest);
```

Comment: That works. But where is addParam and rankAbove described in the api docs?

Comment: addParam: http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitForJava/com/rallydev/rest/request/Request.html#addParam(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: rankAbove: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/ - look for put/post parameters